# Manipulate js $locale anywhere ales than the constructor of the class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, locale, currency

Basically I have this code:

```
class MainController {
    constructor(id, $locale) {
        this.id = id;
        $locale.NUMBER_FORMATS.CURRENCY_SYM = '€'; //this works
    }

    $onInit() {
        this._getCurrency();
    }

    _getCurrency() {
        this.getUserCurrency(this.id).then((currency) => {
            $locale.NUMBER_FORMATS.CURRENCY_SYM = currency; // this does not work
        });
    }
}
```

I want to change my `$locale` but only after a promise is executed and I get the result from it.

**PS:** I also tried to do something just for testing purposes, more exactly to move the code from _getCurrency in the constructor, but the thing is that $locale is not affected also:

```
class MainController {
    constructor(id, $locale) {
        this.id = id;
        $locale.NUMBER_FORMATS.CURRENCY_SYM = '€'; //this works

        this.getUserCurrency(this.id).then((currency) => {
            $locale.NUMBER_FORMATS.CURRENCY_SYM = currency; // this does not work
        });
    }          
}
```

`getUserCurrency` exists in another file and it returns the currency all the time, no worries about that.

EDIT: I used Pankaj Parkar solution but it does not work, check it out:

```
class MainController {
    constructor(id, $locale) {
        this.id = id;
        this.$locale = $locale;
        $locale.NUMBER_FORMATS.CURRENCY_SYM = '€'; //this works
    }

    $onInit() {
        this._getCurrency();
    }

    _getCurrency() {
        this.$locale.NUMBER_FORMATS.CURRENCY_SYM = 'something'; //works but here I don't have the currency response yet
        this.getUserCurrency(this.id).then((currency) => {
            this.$locale.NUMBER_FORMATS.CURRENCY_SYM = currency; // this does not work
        });
    }
}
```

When I say `this does not work` I've noticed that the `$locale` takes the new value but it is not updated in the page, I expect the currency from the page to auto update (`$filter('currency')(input);`) which it does not when the $locale is manipulated inside the promise.

I also tried $evalAsync(), $scope.$apply and $scope.$digest but I get an error saying that the digest is already in progress. However if I do some manual operation on the page, for example a click, the currencies from the page automatically gets updated to the new value that I have set inside the promise.

Comment: Why do you not store the `$locale` in your constructor just like your id? `this.$locale = $locale;`

Answer (score 1):

Currently `$locale` scope is available only in `constructor` function. So it wouldn't be available outside constructor function. You can solve this problem by defining one public variable in your `class` & assign `$locale` value to that variable like below

**ES6 version**

```
class MainController {
    constructor(id, $locale) {
        this.id = id;
        this.$locale = $locale;
    }

    $onInit() {
        this._getCurrency();
    }

    _getCurrency() {
        this.getUserCurrency(this.id).then((currency) => {
            //use _locale as $locale reference
            this.$locale.NUMBER_FORMATS.CURRENCY_SYM = currency;
        });
    }
}
```

---

**Typescript**

```
class MainController {
    _locale: any;
    constructor(id, $locale) {
        this.id = id;
        this._locale = $locale;
    }

    $onInit() {
        this._getCurrency();
    }

    _getCurrency() {
        this.getUserCurrency(this.id).then((currency) => {
            //use _locale as $locale reference
            this._locale.NUMBER_FORMATS.CURRENCY_SYM = currency;
        });
    }
}
```

The shorthand or above approach would be

```
class MainController {
    _locale: any;
    // use public before $locale, 
    // that would make your $locale available in your class. 
    constructor(id, public $locale) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    $onInit() {
        this._getCurrency();
    }

    _getCurrency() {
        this.getUserCurrency(this.id).then((currency) => {
            //use _locale as $locale reference
            this.$locale.NUMBER_FORMATS.CURRENCY_SYM = currency;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try this and come back with an answer. If I am not wrong, I kinda did something like this and it didn't worked, but I will try it and respond to you tomorow morning because now I have to rush in another place. Thanks

Comment: I does not work if it is placed inside: this.getUserCurrency(this.id).then((currency). It works if I drag it outside that block but still inside of the _getCurrency() ; The thing is that I need it insider the promise because there I have the response...

Comment: Wehn you change the $locale currency, automatically all currencies from the page should change. But when you change the $locale currency inside the promise, they don't change.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue could be the fact that getUserCurrency() is missing from your class.

Comment: getUserCurrency() exists in another file, it returns the value.No problem with that